# Jenkins cannot start a docker agent container in declarative pipeline with specific run arguments

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, agent

I have the next setup:

- one amazon EC2 instance;
- Jenkins installed on it;
- Docker instance installed along with Jenkins;
- Docker instance configured as cloud on Jenkins;
- docker agent template is also configured and can be used when the pipeline calls it by label on the agent section.

What I want to accomplish is to use a docker container as the main agent, in a Jenkins pipeline. Now this agent needs to run some build steps and remain running until some other build plan stops the running containers and cleans things up.
This is the pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
        image 'localhost:5000/build_deploy_agent:base'
        label 'build-deploy-agent'
        args  '--network bridge -p 9102:9102'
    }
} 
stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'ps aux'
        }
    }
}
}
```

What happens is:
Jenkins starts the container but it cannot be used to run the script from the stage.
I receive three errors like this one:

```
docker inspect -f . localhost:5000/build_deploy_agent:base
/home/jenkins/workspace/view name/Build plan name@tmp/durable-9a8a9027/script.sh: 1: 
/home/jenkins/workspace/view name/Build plan name@tmp/durable-9a8a9027/script.sh: docker: not found
```

I am definitely doing something wrong here, but I am clueless.

Update 1

- the base docker image used is the 'jenkins/agent' image from the docker hub.
- below I am adding an image with the docker agent setup:

[image]

Comment: `label ` should be match with your definition of slave node. Also you define `-t`. It is tagging but you do not need to tag. You do not create any image. Just use this. `docker {image 'localhost:5000/build_deploy_agent:base' }` This need to be enough.

Comment: If you install Jenkins and docker runtime on the same EC2 instance, you have to add `jenkins` user to `docker` group by using `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins` command, then only Jenkins user will have access to docker CLI.

Comment: @MustafaGüler, I have removed the '-t' and I have updated my question with new info. You can see the docker agent setup page, it has the same label. It is still fails to start the agent properly.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, I have done as you said. Added jenkins user to the docker group, and also done a safeRestart on jenkins. The problem is still there.

Comment: You need to logout and login with the jenkins use than only it will be able to access docker command. Otherwise try to login to the EC2 with Jenkins user and try to run any docker command and see whether u can be able to access or not

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, jenkins is a service user, it doesn't have bin/bash by design. How could I login with the user? The only thing I can do is 'sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins' while I am logged in with ec2-user, but this doesn't do jack.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, give your last input I investigated more. Found out that on jenkins 'System Information' screen, the user is root and the home is also root and I don't think this is right. I will have to change everything to point out to real Jenkins user and /var/lib/jenkins dir, and see how things are going from there.

Comment: Nothing worked.

Comment: Interesting..  Can you please tell me, In EC2 are you running Jenkins in Docker? or you have installed it by using any package maneger like apt, dnf  ?
which option youhave followed from [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/) documentation ?

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, from what I see Jenkins was installed with yum.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

The server on which `jenkins` is running needs the `docker-ce-cli` and the user running the `jenkins` server should be in the `docker` group (if not running as `root`).

---

This example uses everything in `docker` orchestrated using `docker-compose`.

```sh
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── etc
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── default.conf
└── plugins.txt
```

The `docker-compose` spec runs the jenkins server proxied by `nginx`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.19'
    container_name: 'nginx'
    restart: 'always'
    depends_on:
    - 'jenkins'
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - './etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: '.'
    container_name: 'jenkins'
    privileged: true
    restart: 'always'
    expose:
    - '50000'
    - '8080'
    volumes:
    - 'jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
volumes:
  jenkins:
```

**Note**: the `jenkins` home is shared between the `nginx` server and the `jenkins` service for the `userContent`.

**Note**: the `jenkins` service shares the `docker` socket from the host.

A slightly modified [`nginx.conf` from the doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/):

```
upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32;
  server jenkins:8080 max_fails=3;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
server {
  listen *:80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name _;

  charset utf-8;
  ignore_invalid_headers off;

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
    rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
  }
  location /userContent {
    root /var/jenkins_home/;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
      rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
      break;
    }
    sendfile on;
  }
  location / {
    sendfile off;
    proxy_pass         http://jenkins;
    proxy_redirect     default;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header   Connection        $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;
    proxy_buffering            off;
    proxy_request_buffering    off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }
}
```

The `jenkins` image is extended with `docker` and the `jenkins` user is added to the `ping` group (the group ID is `999` which is the `docker` group ID on the host). The `Dockerfile`:

```docker
FROM docker:20.10.5-dind as docker
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
USER root
COPY --from=docker /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN adduser jenkins ping
USER jenkins
```

**Note**: the `jenkins` image is pre-baked with the default suggested plugins plus the [Docker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) and [Docker Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) plugins. The `plugins.txt`:

```
github:1.33.1
pipeline-model-api:1.8.4
scm-api:2.6.4
mailer:1.32.1
workflow-support:3.8
font-awesome-api:5.15.2-2
pipeline-milestone-step:1.3.2
git:4.6.0
plain-credentials:1.7
resource-disposer:0.15
jackson2-api:2.12.1
jquery3-api:3.5.1-3
gradle:1.36
credentials:2.3.15
docker-workflow:1.26
workflow-scm-step:2.12
display-url-api:2.3.4
bootstrap4-api:4.6.0-2
antisamy-markup-formatter:2.1
command-launcher:1.5
pipeline-stage-tags-metadata:1.8.4
snakeyaml-api:1.27.0
pipeline-stage-view:2.19
script-security:1.76
okhttp-api:3.14.9
pipeline-stage-step:2.5
workflow-step-api:2.23
timestamper:1.11.8
pipeline-github-lib:1.0
token-macro:2.13
pam-auth:1.6
workflow-cps-global-lib:2.18
ws-cleanup:0.39
pipeline-model-definition:1.8.4
workflow-aggregator:2.6
jsch:0.1.55.2
matrix-auth:2.6.5
ssh-credentials:1.18.1
ant:1.11
jjwt-api:0.11.2-9.c8b45b8bb173
momentjs:1.1.1
trilead-api:1.0.13
durable-task:1.35
workflow-job:2.40
git-server:1.9
ssh-slaves:1.31.5
plugin-util-api:2.0.0
git-client:3.6.0
lockable-resources:2.10
checks-api:1.5.0
pipeline-input-step:2.12
cloudbees-folder:6.15
pipeline-build-step:2.13
popper-api:1.16.1-2
pipeline-graph-analysis:1.10
matrix-project:1.18
workflow-api:2.41
github-branch-source:2.9.7
workflow-basic-steps:2.23
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.13-1.0
workflow-multibranch:2.22
workflow-cps:2.90
ldap:1.26
build-timeout:1.20
echarts-api:5.0.1-1
pipeline-model-extensions:1.8.4
structs:1.22
junit:1.48
docker-java-api:3.1.5.2
docker-plugin:1.2.2
workflow-durable-task-step:2.38
credentials-binding:1.24
jdk-tool:1.5
bouncycastle-api:2.20
docker-commons:1.17
github-api:1.123
authentication-tokens:1.4
email-ext:2.82
branch-api:2.6.2
pipeline-rest-api:2.19
ace-editor:1.1
handlebars:1.1.1
```

You can bring up the environment using `docker-compose` i.e.: `docker-compose up -d`. You can access the `jenkins` server on http://localhost once the server is started.

Basic `jenkins` pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'ubuntu:20.04' 
            
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'ps -axf'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and console output:
[image: jenkins console output]

**Note**: not using any labels or templates (irrelevant to the problem). The `docker run` is done from the `jenkins` host.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It is different from my setup and a bit had to follow because I am a noob. Regarding what you said above about requirements, I found out that amazon doesn't have any docker-ce-cli packacge available for their amazon-linux EC2 instances. The only way to install docker is 'yum install docker'. And what I see installed is the package docker.x86_64'  with version '19.03.13ce-1.amzn2 ', no docker-ce-cli.

Comment: The docker-ce-cli is e.g. the docker command (the client and daemon are provided as separate binaries, you don’t need the dockerd daemon, just the client, which you should have if you do a full install).

Comment: I am battling a very weird situation here. From what I saw in 'Manage Jenkins' > 'System Information' under 'Environment variables', the user that is setup for Jenkins server is 'root'. Home path is /root. I tried to change it to be user 'jenkins' and I have managed that, but the home path is not changing. Probably this is my problem, or this is one of them.

Comment: Can take it to the chat, might be able to help you out - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229675/jenkins

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this chat.